# Opencart Case sensitive search?

Tags: php, search, opencart

I'm using Opencart Version 1.5.6.4 and the search results appear to be case sensitive?

if i search for "product name" and the actual product name is "PRODUCT NAME" opencart will return no results.

Is there anyway of ignoring the case?

Comment: Did you even bother using Google? http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=19439

Comment: I've have searched extensively, the post you showed applies to a version of Opencart from 4 years ago...Completely different, different issue also.

Comment: Have you checked the code to see if there are any obvious reasons? Have you asked on the OpenCart Forum about this issue?

Comment: Yes, I have asked on the forum, I have replaced the search.php with a fresh download in case there was an issue there.

Answer (score 2):

This has been resolved.

I had updated from a previous version of opencart and imported product information (UTF8_Bin). Since 1.5 the database has been switched to utf8_general_ci collation so text matching in queries is no longer case sensitive.

Just updated the database collation to utf8_general_ci. Issue resolved.